# Not getting the file data while FormData is used

Tags: javascript, file-upload, upload

Here I want to hit the api of the golang to upload a file on the local system using javascript. To get the key, value pair for file I read the FormData method in the javascript and I used it in my code but it will not taking the key, value while I'm assigning the data. I have posted my code.

```
function uploadFile(){
          var url = "http://localhost:8081/shapi/v1/upload";
          var archivoSeleccionado = document.getElementById("myfile");
          var file = archivoSeleccionado.files[0];
          var f = new FormData();
          console.log(file)
          f.append("file", file);
          console.log("f", f)
          var xmlHTTP= new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlHTTP.open("POST", url, true);
          xmlHTTP.send(f);
}
```

In console of  `console.log(file)` it will print

```
File { name: "541660.jpg", lastModified: 1537849576000, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 243477, type: "image/jpeg" }
```

In console of  `console.log("f", f)` it will print:-

```
FormData {  }
```

Can anyone tell me the problem in my code?

Runnable Snippet

```js
function uploadFile() {
  var archivoSeleccionado = document.getElementById("myfile");
  var file = archivoSeleccionado.files[0];
  var f = new FormData();
  console.log(file)
  f.append("file", file);
  console.log("f", f)
}
```

```html
<input id="myfile" type="file" />
<button onclick="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only because when you log the `FormData` it doesn't expose what it has on it by default, you have to explicitly get it, you can do this by using [`get(key)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get) or [`values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/values)

```js
function uploadFile() {
  var archivoSeleccionado = document.getElementById("myfile");
  var file = archivoSeleccionado.files[0];
  var f = new FormData();
  console.log(file)
  f.append("file", file);
  console.log("f", f.get("file"))
}
```

```html
<input id="myfile" type="file" />
<button onclick="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
```